# How to script Random Cell Generator given 3 constraints?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Problem: I want to get a user's input of chosen "Floor" tile, Floor 1 2 or 3. Upon that, the script randomly rolls first Tile Type from the A column, then rolls Tile Formation from that type, then subtracts that tile from the total number of tiles left in the "pile".

So using the image for reference, user inputs Floor 2, script runs and returns Regular, Dead End. It changes Floor 2, Regular, Dead End value from 6 to 5 and returns a prompt "Floor 2, Regular, Dead End".

My issue is I have no idea how to set the limiting parameters within Apps Script that I want. Right now I'm attempting to make it an array, then rolling within that array, but even with that I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax. Any direction or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edited to add solution, so figured it out in case anyone else is interested:

```
function drawCardColumnC() {
  drawCardFromDeck(2, "C");
}

function drawCardColumnD() {
  drawCardFromDeck(3, "D");
}

function drawCardColumnE() {
  drawCardFromDeck(4, "E");
}

function drawCardFromDeck(column, targetColumn) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A3:E30");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var quantities = data.map(function(row) {
    return row[column];
  });

  var validCardIndices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
    if (quantities[i] > 0) {
      validCardIndices.push(i);
    }
  }

  if (validCardIndices.length > 0) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * validCardIndices.length);
    var drawnCardIndex = validCardIndices[randomIndex];
    var drawnCard = data[drawnCardIndex];

    updateCardQuantities(drawnCardIndex, sheet, column);
    sheet.getRange(targetColumn + "32").setValue(drawnCard[0]);
    sheet.getRange(targetColumn + "33").setValue(drawnCard[1]);
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A3:E30");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i][2] = data[i][5];
    data[i][3] = data[i][6];
    data[i][4] = data[i][7];
  }

  sheet.getRange("C32:E33").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("C3:E30").setValues(data);
}

function updateCardQuantities(cardIndex, sheet, column) {
  var quantity = sheet.getRange(cardIndex + 3, column + 3).getValue();
  if (quantity > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(cardIndex + 3, column + 3).setValue(quantity - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: sure so let me add another picture to help understand [link](https://i.imgur.com/PLoXlaW.png). So in this picture I am doing it manually. Someone picks Floor 1 (Cell C2), the script chooses "Regular" (Cell A3) and "Dead End" (Cell B3), so the total for "Floor 1, Regular, Deadend" (Cell C3) number goes from 6 to 5. You can see "Used in game (Cell F3) is 1, and the amount Left is now 5 (Cell i3), does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that when 1 is put into a cell "F3", you wanted to put a value of `C1 - F3` into a cell "I3". Is my understanding correct? But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the relationship between the cells "A3:B3" and the cells "C3:K3". Can I ask you about the detail of the logic for achieving your expected result?

Comment: I actually figured it out! I updated the original post with the solution if you're interested in seeing what I meant.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? It will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: HI. For future reference, please "[DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."

Answer (score 1):

Posting the edit as answer.

```
function drawCardColumnC() {
  drawCardFromDeck(2, "C");
}

function drawCardColumnD() {
  drawCardFromDeck(3, "D");
}

function drawCardColumnE() {
  drawCardFromDeck(4, "E");
}

function drawCardFromDeck(column, targetColumn) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A3:E30");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var quantities = data.map(function(row) {
    return row[column];
  });

  var validCardIndices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
    if (quantities[i] > 0) {
      validCardIndices.push(i);
    }
  }

  if (validCardIndices.length > 0) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * validCardIndices.length);
    var drawnCardIndex = validCardIndices[randomIndex];
    var drawnCard = data[drawnCardIndex];

    updateCardQuantities(drawnCardIndex, sheet, column);
    sheet.getRange(targetColumn + "32").setValue(drawnCard[0]);
    sheet.getRange(targetColumn + "33").setValue(drawnCard[1]);
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A3:E30");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i][2] = data[i][5];
    data[i][3] = data[i][6];
    data[i][4] = data[i][7];
  }

  sheet.getRange("C32:E33").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("C3:E30").setValues(data);
}

function updateCardQuantities(cardIndex, sheet, column) {
  var quantity = sheet.getRange(cardIndex + 3, column + 3).getValue();
  if (quantity > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(cardIndex + 3, column + 3).setValue(quantity - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).